# Configure IdentityServerJwt Authentication with Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-identity, hangfire

I have an Blazor webassembly application which uses IdentityServerJwt AddAuthentication and is working with Hangfire. I am trying to configure Hangfire to `allow only users who are admins` authorization based on the article [here](https://sahansera.dev/securing-hangfire-dashboard-with-endpoint-routing-auth-policy-aspnetcore/) but I am getting an `No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'` error. What should I add as an `AuthenticationSchemes`. JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` does not work.

What am I missing?

```
    public partial class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }    
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            string handfirepolicyname="HangfirePolicyName";
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
...Code removed for brevity
    services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                  options.AddPolicy(handfirepolicyname, builder =>
                  {                    builder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    builder.RequireRole("admin");
                  });
                });        
                var hangfireConnectionstring = "SomeHangfireDatabaseConnectionString";
                var mySqlStorageOptions = new MySqlStorageOptions();
                var mySqlStorage = new MySqlStorage(hangfireConnectionstring, mySqlStorageOptions);
                services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseStorage(mySqlStorage));
                services.AddHangfireServer();
    }        
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationIdentityDbContext identityDbContext)
            {
...Code removed for brevity
                app.UseIdentityServer();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                //UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization should be before UseHangfireDashboard
                app.UseHangfireDashboard();    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                  endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
                  {
                    Authorization = new List<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter> { }
                  }).RequireAuthorization(handfirepolicyname);
                });
    
    }
```

**Error:**

```
No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external, IdentityServerJwt, IdentityServerJwtBearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Bearer",...)?
```

Comment: Do you forget to configure the authentication(add the bearer option)? Please refer to  [link](https://github.com/GestionSystemesTelecom/fake-authentication-jwtbearer/issues/3)

Answer (score 0):

by adding

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase{}
```

on top of the controller